# Accessing inherited methods that have been overridden

Tags: python

```
class A:
    def start(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def start(self):
        super(A,self).start()

b = B()
b.start()
```

Gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/a.py", line 10, in <module>
    b.start()
  File "C:/Python32/a.py", line 7, in start
    super(A,self).start()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'start'
```

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in [python doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super), super works only for new style class, ie :

> **Note** super() only works for new-style classes.

So you should do something like this :

```
class A(object):    # inherit from object to be a new style class
    def start(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def start(self):
        super(B,self).start()   # the first arg of super is the current class

b = B()
b.start()
```